# Add a new line using SetWindowText() Function

Tags: winapi, editbox

I have Created an Edit window. 
I want one string to be displayed in one line and the other string to be displayed on the other line, but the code I am executing only displays the second string. below is my code snippet:

```
hWndEdit = CreateWindow("EDIT", // We are creating an Edit control
                                NULL,   // Leave the control empty
                                WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_HSCROLL |
                                WS_VSCROLL | ES_LEFT | ES_MULTILINE |
                                ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_AUTOVSCROLL,
                                10, 10,1000, 1000,
                                hWnd,
                                0,
                                hInst,NULL);
SetWindowText(hWndEdit, TEXT("\r\nFirst string\r\n"));

SetWindowText(hWndEdit, TEXT("\r\nSecond string"));
```

**OUTPUT:**
[image: OUTPUT]

Comment: I suggest a thorough review of the [SetWindowText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633546(v=vs.85).aspx), especially the part that fundamentally describes how the function lives up to its namesake : SetWindowText(). Its not AppendWindowText(). Since this is an edit control I would surmise a visit to [Edit Control Messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff485923(v=vs.85).aspx) and the things they can do for you may be an interesting read.

Comment: @WhozCraig It seems like I keep reading great comments from you. Please start posting them as answers so I can start upvoting them!

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks, Cody. Your avatar is *awesome*, by-the-way. I've only been doing this for about 9 active months, but sometimes I just forget to post the answer as that. Or I don't feel it is really a solid contribution as an answer. There are times when RTFM is appropriate as such, but I just drop a comment. Habit, I guess.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are only seeing the last line because `SetWindowText()` replaces the entire contents of the window in one go.

If you want to display both lines at one time, simply concatenate them together in a single call to `SetWindowText()`:

```
SetWindowText(hWndEdit, TEXT("\r\nFirst string\r\n\r\nSecond string"));
```

On the other hand, if you want to insert them at different times, you have to use the `EM_SETSEL` message to place the edit caret at the end of the window and then use the `EM_REPLACESEL` message to insert text at the current caret position, as described in this article:

[How To Programatically Append Text to an Edit Control](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/109550)

For example:

```
void AppendText(HWND hEditWnd, LPCTSTR Text)
{
    int idx = GetWindowTextLength(hEditWnd);
    SendMessage(hEditWnd, EM_SETSEL, (WPARAM)idx, (LPARAM)idx);
    SendMessage(hEditWnd, EM_REPLACESEL, 0, (LPARAM)Text);
}
```

.

```
AppendText(hWndEdit, TEXT("\r\nFirst string\r\n"));
AppendText(hWndEdit, TEXT("\r\nSecond string"));
```

Comment: +1, especially for the constructive use of control messages (which I tried to not-so-shyly drop a hint to look at in the opening comment).

Answer (score 2):

```
hWndEdit = CreateWindow("EDIT", // We are creating an Edit control
                                NULL,   // Leave the control empty
                                WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_HSCROLL |
                                WS_VSCROLL | ES_LEFT | ES_MULTILINE |
                                ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_AUTOVSCROLL,
                                10, 10,1000, 1000,
                                hWnd,
                                0,
                                hInst,NULL);
        SetWindowText(hWndEdit, TEXT("\r\nFirst string\r\n\r\nSecond string"));
```

or

```
        SetWindowText(hWndEdit, TEXT("\r\nFirst string\r\n"));

        char* buf = malloc(100);
        memset(buf, '\0', 100);

        GetWindowText(hWndEdit, (LPTSTR)buf, 100);
        strcat(buf, "\r\nSecond string");
        SetWindowText(hWndEdit, (LPTSTR)buf);
```

Comment: Thank you for helping :) Both the Answers were of my use :)